# Active Record Access - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a model Rating and I do `ratings = Rating.all` and then `ratings.where ("score = ?", 3)`. In the first statement Rails will search all ratings in the database, what happens in the second command? Rails will access the database again or it will uses the ratings that are loaded into memory?

I ask because I need all the database records but than I need to segregate with `where` or equivalent with the least database request possible, what is the best practice for this type of implementation?

Comment: btw you can check your ideas just running commands in a console and look at a result in log/*.rb

Answer (score 0):

Running either of those queries won't touch the database, those will only create an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, only when you try to access the data will it actually run the query, otherwise the object stays as a relation object ready to be chained with other methods.

If you try to loop on the data for example in both states, then 2 queries would be run, but if you loop on the same object twice, the data is fetched once, and the 2nd time will get the cached data.

Comment: In this case what should I do if I WANT to retrieve all records in db to only make 1 request and them work with the data in memory. Using `where` or others methods....

Comment: is score a direct attribute inside rating? if so you could do the processing outside the database, `ratings.select{ |rating| rating.score == 3 }`